# Common object list for component validate in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I have a common object for example

```
Const Color = {
    primary: blue,
    danger: red,
    warning: orange
}
```

Same thing with Size etc…

I use this object for validate component and add style.

In which folder can I add these objects in the root? Many use models/color.js is correct?

Comment: technically this is not really a model : Interface or Class .
IMO it looks like more config files, so I would put them in a config folder

Comment: Ah ok! 

For example: config/color.js etc? Correct?

Comment: yes as you want